# 4 checkboxes, if 2 or more checkboxes are checked I want to randomly trigger 1 function that is associated with one of the checkboxes

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

Sorry if the title is a mess, let me try to make it easier...

Let's say the checkboxes return the following for each:

```
checkboxOne = false;
checkboxTwo = true;
checkboxThree = true;
checkboxFour = true;
```

I also have 4 functions:

```
userFuncOne() {...}
userFuncTwo() {...}
userFuncThree() {...}
userFuncFour() {...}
```

If 2 or more of the checkboxes are true, I would like to have one of the functions triggered at random, but only the ones that are associated with a `true` value. So in the example above, `userFuncOne()` could not be triggered, but the rest could, and only one of them gets triggered randomly.

How would I do this most effectively? Obviously I could do a bunch of if's and else's but that seems terribly inefficient.

Is there a better way? Thanks!

Comment: You could possibly add all the available functions into an array, pick a random function and execute it? So listen to the change event for each check box if it is true add the function to the array, otherwise if it is false remove it, then if the length is >=2, use the random function to grab a random index in the array and execute the function?

Comment: why `most effectively` - you either do it right or wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a sample snippet from my comment, maybe what you are after? You will probably want to tweak it, it is just a proof of concept :)

```js
function funcA(){console.log('funcA');}
function funcB(){console.log('funcB');}
function funcC(){console.log('funcC');}
function funcD(){console.log('funcD');}

var functionList = [];

function oncheckBoxClick(cBox){
  var funName = cBox.dataset.fname;
  if(cBox.checked){
    functionList.push(funName);
  }
  else{    
    var index = functionList.indexOf(funName);    
      
    if (index > -1) {
      functionList.splice(index, 1);
    }
  }
  
   if(functionList.length>=2){
     var randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * functionList.length);
     this[functionList[randomIndex]]();   
     }
    
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox"  onclick="oncheckBoxClick(this)" data-fname="funcA" />
<input type="checkbox"  onclick="oncheckBoxClick(this)" data-fname="funcB" />
<input type="checkbox"  onclick="oncheckBoxClick(this)" data-fname="funcC" />
<input type="checkbox"  onclick="oncheckBoxClick(this)" data-fname="funcD" />
```